# "The following" vs. "Following"

Tags: definite-article

I wrote

> "Following examples show ..."

and my colleague revised it as

> "The following examples show ..."

Why do we need "the" here even though the examples have not been mentioned before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the definite article because they are still specific examples, even though you haven't mentioned them before.  They're not just *any* examples, they're specifically **the following** examples, as opposed to **the best examples** or **the examples of history** or **the examples I found in my sock drawer**.

Whether something has been mentioned before is a good rule of thumb, but it is not the only rule for when you should use the definite article.

Reference: [Using Articles](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)

Answer (score 3):

Because that rule you refer to does not apply about 70% of the time. Go and read anything in English and count the number of times a noun phrase is used for the first time with *the*.

A writer/speaker can use a definite noun phrase whenever he thinks the reader/listener can identify *which* thing(s) he is talking about.

The definite noun phrase *the following examples* contains enough information for the reader to identify *which examples* are being talked about. The examples that the definite noun phrase refers to are the ones that are about to be mentioned.

This type of reference is a cataphoric reference, which is a fancy way of saying that it refers to something that comes later in the text.

Answer (score -1):

When a sentence begins with *Following examples show* the reader might think ***following*** is a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) and therefore expect the sentence to be about the nature of following examples in general. *The following examples show* avoids this possibility.