# "The following" or "following"

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-article

When would it be acceptable to use the following form?

> From a order paid with the credit card we **get following** response: ...
> over
> From a order paid with the credit card we **get the following** response: ...

I am pretty sure that saying "**the**" before "**following**" is not necessarily required here, even if it's not the most literary way of writing.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use “the”.

Not using “the” is very general, and doesn’t suggest you received something specific and are now talking about that specific thing.

Let’s consider the meanings of the following:

> We got responses.

A very simple statement that means what it says.

> We got some responses.

This means we received responses, but could have received more.

> We got the responses.

This refers to specific responses. Either we are about to specify those, or the listener already knows what responses we were expecting.

> We got the response.

Singular version of the above.

> We got response.

This is the sort of thing you’d hear among professionals in an industry, e.g., technology or the armed services, where responses to certain things are so routine and commonplace, that they are referenced as an institution or process, i.e. just “response”.

> We got a response.

This is what you would say if you were talking more generally about a single response, and not intending to specify what the response was.

Answer (score 0):

One link is https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/following-or-the-following

Your question has already been answered here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100202/the-following-vs-following

(not sure if it is a duplicate considering it is on another part of these communities, so I will let someone more experienced deal with this)

Comment: I would type more on the answer itself, instead of just putting a bunch of links, but I just got a cast so typing is really hard for me. Also,  you really need to do some research before you post your question because the answer is easy to find.

Comment: Thank you Taryn, the URLS are much appreciated. I promise to also post research I have done in the  "PRE" before jumping in . Still, up to this moment I am not able to understand if I can use :  **We  got following response: ...**  . If not usable in this form , understand and know why to avoid it.